# python 'super' in multiple inheritance - unexpected code output

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance, super

I am relatively new to python OOP.
Although I have some experience with JAVA OOP and I know the meaning of the method 'super', I struggle to understand how does it works in python when I have multiple inheritances (which doesn't exist in JAVA)

After digging to find some answers, I read that according to the inheritances graph, for every class python made a Method Resolution Order (MRO) to determine in what order to look for an instance method.

I also read that the MRO is determined by "old style" or "new style", depending on my python version. 
I have python 3.7 so I use the "new style" method.

If I understand correctly, every time I override a method and call 'super', python goes to the method in the class that appears **after** the current class in the MRO.

Indeed, When I run the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def go(self):
        print("go A go!")

class B(A):
    def go(self):
        super(B, self).go()
        print("go B go!")

class C(A):
    def go(self):
        super(C, self).go()
        print("go C go!")

class D(B,C):
    def go(self):
        super(D, self).go()
        print("go D go!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = D()
    d.go()
    print(D.__mro__)
```

I got the output:

```
go A go!
go C go!
go B go!
go D go!
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So far so good, but when I tried to run the following code:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        print('this is A')

class B(object):
    def foo(self):
        print('this is B')

class AB(A,B):
    def foo(self):
        super(AB,self).foo()
        print('this is AB')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = AB()
    x.foo()
    print(AB.__mro__)
```

I got the output:

```
this is A
this is AB
(<class '__main__.AB'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Rather than the output as I was expected to be:

```
this is B
this is A
this is AB
(<class '__main__.AB'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So apparently I don't understand what is going on...

Any explanation for this situation, and also about how exactly python determines the MRO (according to the "new style") will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: I read this already... didn't find an answer to my problem...

Comment: Did you check the Guido van Rossum's paper about MRO?: http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: Also read [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/). Short answer: in a cooperative inheritance hierarchy, exactly *one* class is allowed to define `foo` that doesn't call `super().foo()`. You have two: `A` and `B`. One class has to be the "base" which will appear last in the MRO of any subclass inheriting from a `foo`-providing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your classes are not cooperatively defined. Both `A` and `B` think that it has introduce `foo`, and therefore there is no need to call `super().foo`, because each thinks that it will be the last class in any potential MRO to define `foo`. `AB` proves that is not the case.

When you call `AB.foo`, the first thing it does is call `A.foo`. However, `A.foo` doesn't use `super`, so the chain ends, and `B.foo` never gets called.

In a properly designed hierarchy, exactly *one* class "introduces" a method, and is responsible for terminating the chain by not calling `super`. Any other class that wants to be part of the hierarchy is responsible for calling `super`.

In your `A`/`B`/`AB` case, you have a few options:

1. Have both `A` and `B` inherit from `FooBase`, and have each of them call `super().foo()` from its implementation of `foo`. `FooBase.foo` itself does not call `super`.
2. Instead of `AB` inheriting directly from `A` and `B`, have it inherit from wrappers around one or both of them, where the wrapper correctly implements cooperative inheritance. (See [Python's super() considered super!.](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for more details.)

   As an example, here we wrap `A` and let `B` act as the base for `foo`:

   ```
   class A:
       def foo(self):
           print('this is A')


   class AWrapper:
       def __init__(self, **kwargs):
           super().__init__()
           self.a = A()

       def foo(self):
           super().foo()
           self.a.foo()


   class B(object):
       def foo(self):
           print('this is B')

   # Important: AWrapper must come first
   class AB(AWrapper, B):
       def foo(self):
           super().foo()
           print('this is AB')

   AB().foo()
   ```

Note this gets more complicated if `__init__` itself needs to be defined in `A` and `B`; see the linked article for more advice on making `__init__` work properly in a cooperative inheritance setting.